# Why is the angle made by the two bodies with the horizontal 45 degrees after collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

A proton of mass $m$ collides elastically with a particle of unknown mass at rest. After the collision the proton and the unknown particle are seen moving at an angle of $90^o$ with respect to each other. What is the mass of unknown particle in terms of the mass of proton?

Comment: Just because they move off at right angles to each other doesn't mean they move off at 45 degrees to the horizontal each.

Comment: Where is you effort at solving the problem.?

Comment: sounds like a billiards problem, no?

Comment: @BobD I tried by taking the two angles as theta 1 and theta 2

Comment: @BobD I cant upload  what  I solved cause I don’t have enough experience I believe so I’m sorry

Comment: @BobD I see u are a physicist could u help me out

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.careers360.com/engineering/question-i-need-help-with-work-energy-and-power-jee-main-2/&ved=2ahUKEwjv_c3GiKjsAhWQIbcAHXMABZsQFjAKegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2hdSCUGg7zu0x7dXoA_ZD- might help

Comment: Thank u Anusha. :3

Answer (score 0):

In order to conserve and energy and momentum in a collision, the speed with which each particle leaves the center of mass must be the same as the speed which they had while approaching, and these two are in opposite directions.  If the two masses are equal and one is at rest before the collision, both speeds in the center of mass system are equal to v = Vo/2 which is also the speed of the center of mass in the original system. To convert back from the CM system to the original requires vector triangles which can define two identical parallelograms. It can be shown that the angle between the diagonals of the parallelograms is 90 degrees.  This shows that the angle between the two velocities leaving the collision is 90 degrees, and this does not require that each is at 45 degrees with the original direction  of motion.  However, I do not know that the 90 degree angle requires equal masses. Both at 45 degrees probably does.